# Eps file weirdly compiled

Tags: graphics, compiling, overleaf, eps, matlab

I have an overleaf project with a number of `.eps` files. I use the `graphicx` package to include them in the final `.pdf`.
Most of the files compile properly, but two of them, which have labels on them (made in Matlab) compile weirdly:

[image: Weirdly compiled Eps file]

The second image looks simalar. I included the file like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Dipol_24h_Mean_fHz.eps}
\caption{Mean acceleration spectral density on dipol laser table magnified}
\label{fig:dipol24hmean500}
\end{figure}
```

However, if I download the pdf it looks good.
I tried to compile it in a seperate `.tex` file and it looks fine.
Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: This likely isn't a problem with the compiled document (download the PDF to check), it is likely a problem with the PDF viewer, and ultimately a browser issue. I'm on the Overleaf support team - we've seen some examples of this caused by plugins/extensions recently. Please disable your extensions and refresh the page. If you would like some more troubleshooting advice, please get in touch with support@overleaf.com.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I disabled all of my extensions, but i still have the same issue. I quickly checked the document in a other browser - i usually use Opera- and it looks good.